# What should i do when pIctures on my iphone are not rotating when i rotate the device,?

Tags: iphone

I have a relatively new iphone 4s and suddenly the other day when i rotate the phone nothing on the device (pictures, etc) don't rotate anymore.

What is the best way to figure out what is going on?  I tried rebooting the device but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rotation lock may have been turned on.

To change this:

1. **Double-tap the home button** to show the app switcher at the bottom.
2. **Swipe to the right**, and you'll see the music controls and the rotation lock switch (the icon at the far left). If rotation is locked, there will be a lock symbol inside the arrow circle.
3. **Tap the rotation switch** to unlock it. (The text: 'Portrait Orientation Unlocked' will appear at the bottom).

This has changed with recent (2015) updates. On the home screen slide your thumb from the bottom up to get to the quick settings. On the top right you should see the rotation lock. Tap it and rotate should work again.